# Python outputs CR CR LF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mingw, eol

I am in the process of writing a testing script that will simply run an *.EXE file with a few arguments, and then output the result to a file.  I have one *.sh testing script that correctly runs the tests (but requires manual updating for more tests).  The lines in this script look like this:

```
blah.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 > ../test/arg4/arg4.out
```

I have written a python script to automatically generate the arguments based on a few simple python modules (it's pretty rough right now):

```
import os
import subprocess

for test_dir in os.listdir():
    if not os.path.isdir(test_dir):
        continue
    # load a few variables from the ./test_dir/test_dir.py module
    test_module = getattr(__import__(test_dir, fromlist=[test_dir]), test_dir)

    # These arguments are relative paths, fix the paths
    arg1 = os.path.join(test_dir, test_module.ARG1)
    arg2 = os.path.join(test_dir, test_module.ARG2)
    arg3 = os.path.join(test_dir, test_module.ARG3)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["../bin/blah.exe", arg1, arg2, arg3], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout_txt = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")

    with open(os.path.join(test_dir, test_dir + '.out'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(stdout_txt)
```

I have opened the files to compare and while the script is working, I ran across a problem.  The first (shell) solution outputs correct line-endings.  The second (python) solution outputs lines ending with CR CR LF.  This looks correct in Notepad, but in Notepad++, every other line appears to be blank:

[image: These lines should have no empty lines between them]

**Why is the output from python giving improper line endings?**

**How can I correct the line endings?** (change CR CR LF to CR LF without having to write another script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `universal_newlines=True` argument to `Popen` (see http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: Wow, that was an easy fix, thanks!  I wonder why that's not enabled by default (will accept when enough time has passed).

Comment: @Darthfett: it's not Python that's using the linefeeds you're seeing, and the default behavior of not messing with the output of the process in any way seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Wooble Ah, I didn't know exactly what was happening here.  Thanks!  If that's true, then since I've inherited the source for the .EXE, I guess that means I potentially have some work to do.